# On the non-equivalency of information density between radices

Tags: number-theory, information-theory

Normally when people talk about numerical bases, it is said that they are entirely equivalent.  However, is it not true that the lower the radix, the greater is the information density that is immediately conveyed?  For example the binary 11111 is equivalent to the decimal 31, but the former provides more immediate information.  Transforming (encoding or decoding) between these systems then necessarily requires an algorithmic computation.

If this is correct, what are the immediate ramifications?

Comment: In what sense does 11111 "provide more immediate information"?

Comment: If you look at it like a machine, you can hook up five pins to that number and you can immediately use the information from each pin to do further work.  In this case, the work would be algorithmic transformations based on the value of the pin, which would have the inherent information of the power of two as given by the order of the individual pins.   Whereas 31 only has two pins, each containing inherent information of the power of ten.  They are equivalent in the sense that an algorithm can convert that information into any mathematical equivalency, but this requires work.

Comment: To put it more briefly, 11111 gives the user 5 immediate inherent facts about the number, whereas 31 gives the user only 2.  All other facts must be computed at the cost of energy.

Comment: But a base-10 digit is one of 10 possibilities, whereas a binary digit is just one of 2 possibilities, so a base-10 digit conveys more information than a base-2 digit.

Comment: Well if that is the correct way to look at it, it still implies that one has higher informational density than the other.  Which is really what I am trying to understand here, whether or not my example was phrased entirely correctly.

Comment: It is difficult when the radix is greater than two, as one begins 'counting' when thinking of it, rather than working with a strictly boolean logical operator.  But this is also true for the exponentiation values as it is for the digit magnitude.  So I think the correct basis is to disregard this "hard-wired" information which is part of the general definition of a radix, and only focus on the additional computations required to perform further equivalency transformations.  In this sense, I think binary is the most information dense and the least encoded...

Answer (score 0):

In binary representation, each symbol can represent two values; in information theory terms, that amounts to $1$ bit per symbol. In decimal representation, each symbol can represent ten values; that amounts to $\log_2(10)=3.3219$ bits per symbol. So, yes, decimal representation has more information density ($3.32$ times), and hence it's more efficient (in some sense). And hexadecimal representation has $4$ times more.

I'm not sure what "immediate ramifications" you are thinking of.